# Need postman to wait for the population of an array before running tests, tried lots and lot, it's just not working :(

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, postman, sequential

Consider the script below, I need the 2nd for loop to finish running before the tests are run, I have tried lots, the only thing that works is setting interval, but this is problematic as it sporadically fails when run on postman monitor, is there another surefire way to make sure these tests are not run until the for loop has completed and populated the transitionNamesArray?

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var getStateByIdUrl = pm.environment.get("host") + "/" + pm.environment.get("project-key") + "/states/";
var authToken = pm.environment.get("ctp_access_token");
let transitionsArray = jsonData.transitions;
let transitionNamesArray = [];
let transitionIdsArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.transitions.length; i++) {
    transitionIdsArray.push(jsonData.transitions[i].id);
}

console.log(transitionIdsArray)

async function getTransitionNames() {
    for (let t = 0; t < transitionIdsArray.length; t++) {
        const getRequestTransitions = {
            url: getStateByIdUrl + transitionIdsArray[t],
            method: 'GET',
            header: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
            }
        };

        await pm.sendRequest(getRequestTransitions, (err, res) => {
            res = res.json();
            transitionNamesArray.push(res.name['en'])
            console.log(transitionNamesArray);
        })

    }
    pm.test("Transitions contain 'Partially Delivered' and 'Delivered'", () => {
        pm.expect(transitionNamesArray).to.include("Delivered");
        pm.expect(transitionNamesArray).to.include("Partially Delivered");
    })

}

getTransitionNames()
```

I have tried running the `getTransitionNames()` function within pm.test() function, thinking it would run the function before attempting the pm.expect(), no luck, have tried loads of things, with no luck, at my wits' end, please help :(

Comment: It looks like you're trying to await a function that uses callbacks (`sendRequest()`). Callbacks aren't promises and can't be awaited. You probably want to search for how to turn a callback into a promise. You might also need to `await res.json()` if that's an async method.

Comment: Yeah, admittedly I haven't yet quite gotten my head around async functions and promises, looking into though, but if you have any suggestions on how I might refactor the above to make it valid, would be much appreciated!